# Why does it not work? (send function as parameter by Runnable in java )

Tags: java, runnable

I have a project in java, and I have a problem.

**Description of goal**:

In Form A (`MainForm`) I have some buttons in `enable(false)` mode.
I have a function `LockOrUnlockButtons()` that checks some conditions and if this function return true then the buttons make enable(true) state . 
I want to call this function for "event of the closing of Form B" (`AddCstmrForm`).

I tried to solve this goal with receiving this function as  parameter:

```
public Void AddCstmrForm(Runnable myFunc) {
    .....
    ....
    }
```

**The problem:**

But in Form A (`MainForm`), when I send the function `LockOrUnlockButtons()`  to the Constructor of Form B (`AddCstmrForm`) i got Error:

```
Constructor AddCstmrForm in class AddCstmrForm cannot be applied to given types.
  required: no arguments.
  founf: Void
```

What did I do wrong?

Harel

**THE CODE:**
*in the Form A ,(`MainForm`):*

```
private void buttonAddNewCstmrCrdActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
         AddCstmrForm addCstmr = null;
        try 
        {
            addCstmr = new  AddCstmrForm(LockOrUnlockButtons());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            addCstmr.show();
}

   private Void LockOrUnlockButtons() throws Exception
    {
         if(sngltn.GetAllCustemers().size()==0) 
            buttonUpdateAddActivityCstmrCrd.setEnabled(false);
         else
              buttonUpdateAddActivityCstmrCrd.setEnabled(true);

         if(sngltn.GetAllCustemers().size()==0) 
            buttonDeleteCstmrCrd.setEnabled(false);
         else
            buttonDeleteCstmrCrd.setEnabled(true);

         if(sngltn.GetAllCustemers().size()==0) 
            buttonQueriesViewData.setEnabled(false);
         else
            buttonQueriesViewData.setEnabled(true); 
         return null;
    }
```

*in the Form B(`AddCstmrForm`): *

```
public class AddCstmrForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...............
    .............
    .........
    private Runnable MainFormLockOrUnlockButton;
    ........
    public Void AddCstmrForm(Runnable myFunc) throws Exception {
    initComponents();
    ..............
    ..........
    ......
    this.MainFormLockOrUnlockButton = myFunc;
    return null;
    }
    ..............
    ..........
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a constructor:

```
public Void AddCstmrForm(Runnable myFunc) throws Exception {
    initComponents();
    ...
}
```

It's a method called `AddCstmrForm` with a `Void` return type.

I think you meant:

```
public AddCstmrForm(Runnable myFunc) throws Exception {
    initComponents();
    ...
}
```

You *also* need to create a `Runnable` to call your `LockOrUnlockButtons` method. For example:

```
AddCstmrForm addCstmr = new AddCstmrForm(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        LockOrUnlockButtons();
    }
});
```

Unless you're using Java 8, in which case you could write:

```
AddCstmrForm addCstmr = new AddCstmrForm(this::LockOrUnlockButtons);
```

Additionally, your `LockOrUnlockButtons` can be simplified significantly:

```
private void LockOrUnlockButtons() throws Exception {
    boolean anyCustomers = !sngltn.GetAllCustemers().isEmpty();
    buttonUpdateAddActivityCstmrCrd.setEnabled(anyCustomers);
    buttonDeleteCstmrCrd.setEnabled(anyCustomers);
    buttonQueriesViewData.setEnabled(anyCustomers);
}
```

(I'd also *strongly* advise you to follow Java naming conventions, use a return type of `void` rather than `Void` unless you really need to, and avoid `throws Exception`. You should revisit your exception handling approach in general, by the looks of things.)

Comment: ok.
i fix my "not constructor" to "real consctructor"!
but But I got stuck when I wanted to add thecreate a Runnable to call my LockOrUnlockButtons method.
I want to call her for an event of closing AddCstmrForm, 
Could you please guide me more what should I write?

Comment: And have you fixed the way you're trying to create a `Runnable`?

Comment: But I'm still stuck in, what I should write for Runnable to call my LockOrUnlockButtons method.
I want to call her for an event of closing AddCstmrForm, Could you please guide me more what should I write?

Answer (score 1):

A "Runnable" is not just an arbitrary function; it is an instance of a class that implements the Runnable interface. The syntax you're using is, frankly, extremely creative; but it is simply wrong.